# Why is Django retrieving all the reverse foreign objects

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have the following models created in django:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    route = models.ForeignKey('B', related_name='b')
    

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And I want to filter the elements of 'B' without accessing the elements of A. The problem is that when I run the following query (supposing there are 4 objects of A related to one object of B with id equal to 1):

```py
B.objects.filter(id='1')
```

I get printed 4 different sql queries, fetching all related objects of A. I do not know why that's happening. I have tried

```py
B.objects.filter(id='1').select_related('b')
```

But it does not work for some reason. I do not want to do those hits to the database, ideally, I would want to ignore/exclude those objects because I only want the objects of B.

Additional info:

- `django version`: 1.11
- `python version`: 2.7

Comment: Are the queries correct? You filtered by id in the example.

Comment: Mm that's just an example, but I filter by id only in the real model it works fine.

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado, Which objects do you still want, if you filter query for B object by ID.

Comment: I want the result of the query only contain objects with the attributes of B, that is, 'name'. For some reason, django is retrieving the objects from A, too.

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado You must be getting those other queries because you _use_ them somewhere for some reason..., The fact that you don't show enough code in your question only makes this harder for people to help. Please see how to write a [mre]. Perhaps if you get those queries just by running `B.objects.filter(id='1')` then you are using them in the `__str__` method of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A(models.Model):
    route = models.ForeignKey('B', related_name='a')
    

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I think you should try:

```
B.objects.prefetch_related('a').filter(id='1')
```

select_related is for foreign key
prefetch_related is for manytomany fields or reverse lookup relationship.

Comment: As explained in the question, I would like to exclude those objects, if possible. I do not want to make that one hit bigger than necessary, I only want objects from model B.

Comment: And even if I use `prefetch_related`, I'm still seeing those sql statements appear when I run `B.objects.prefetch_related('a').filter(id=1)`

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado write the `prefetch_related` _last_ as further filtering would invalidate all prefetching.